# React-Router-Dom using React-Sound

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm making a website which requires the use of a router to display different pages. I decided to use React since it's simple to use. However, I stumbled across a problem when trying to incorporate sound.

Basically, since I am making a router system, I cannot make my sound work so that if I change the page, the sound does not break and continues from where it stopped when the user clicked a button to change the page.

What I am trying to model is similar to Spotify's sound system, where upon clicking a playlist or a profile link, the music currently being played does not break or restart from the beginning. My website currently does exactly that: When changing the page, the sound starts from the beginning. This is due to the fact that, when using `react-router-dom`, I believe what it happening is that the entire page gets rendered again, and with it the sound as well.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? How can I work around this? Thanks for your responses!

Edit: Thanks for the tip, Max. Here is my code (App.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Gallery2018 from "./components/Gallery2018";
import Song from "./components/Song";
import Main from "./pages/Main";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Events from "./pages/Events";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Donate from "./pages/Donate";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom"

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Song />
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact={true} path = "/" render={() => (
            <div className = "App">
              <Main />
            </div>
          )}/>
          <Route exact={true} path = "/about" render={() => (
            <div className = "App">
              <About />
            </div>
          )}/>
          <Route exact={true} path = "/events" render={() => (
            <div className = "App">
              <Events />
            </div>
          )}/>
          <Route exact={true} path = "/contact" render={() => (
            <div className = "App">
              <Contact />
            </div>
          )}/>
          <Route exact={true} path = "/donate" render={() => (
            <div className = "App">
              <Donate />
            </div>
          )}/>
          <Route exact={true} path = "/gallery2018" render={() => (
            <div className = "App">
              <Gallery2018 />
            </div>
          )}/>
          <div className="copyright text-center" id="footer">© 2018 Aligarh Alumni Association New York. All Rights Reserved.</div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Most of the code here is pretty redundant, so I'll explain what you need to see. Basically, I have a router mechanism being used here, as well as a component called "Song," who's code is here:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sound from "react-sound";
import soundfile from "./tarana.mp3";

class Song extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Sound 
                url = {soundfile}
                playStatus = {Sound.status.PLAYING}
                playFromPosition = {8000}
                onLoading={this.handleSongLoading}
                onPlaying={this.handleSongPlaying}
                onFinishedPlaying={this.handleSongFinishedPlaying}
             />
        )
    }
}

export default Song
```

This Song comes from the react-sound package, which is designed to add music to your applications. With the way my code is set up right now, in App.js, since I have a routing mechanism where I render the pages every time the corresponding button is clicked to change the page, the Song component is also rendered as well, causing the music to start from the beginning. I would like it so that when changing the page, the Song component will not be interrupted by the changing of the pages. Is there a way to do that using the packages I currently have? Or should I change my packages? Thanks again!

Edit 2: Also, if you were wondering where my buttons are for the pathing, the links are in the Navbar component.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!  Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Some code to reproduce the problem would really help!  Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! I edited my comment to help give some more clarification. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you believe the router is responsible: You could try raising the `<Song/>` component to the same level as the `<BrowserRouter/>` component, rather than nesting it within

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe I didn't think to put the Song component outside the BrowserRouter component. That actually worked! Thanks so much, I was going crazy with trying to figure out what to do since yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Arman Charan for the answer!

Basically, I didn't put the  component outside the  block. After doing so, it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-nested-routing .   has an example of nested components.

If the sound is played at the root ( `const App = ()` in the example ), it will continue after changing routes (in the example it should be a component similar to how they use the `<header />` to be visible in all nested routes)

Comment: Hopefully my edit will give some more clarification to my problem. My code is set up in a similar way to the example you gave, but if you change the page to go from say "/" to "/about", the song is played from the beginning instead of where it was before the page was changed.